# Reduce high power consumption of Intel Wifi 6 AX201

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, intel

According to `$ powertop`, the WiFi card (Intel Wifi 6 AX201) in my Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen9 (running Ubuntu 21.04) is often drawing between 4 and 5W in battery mode, thereby reducing my laptop's battery life by several hours. This happens while my laptop is connected to a wifi network and even when there's little to no traffic occurring on the wifi interface.

I find this incredible, given that I've been using Intel Wifi cards in other laptops over the years and none of them have drawn *that* much power.

Is there any way for me to reduce the wifi card's power consumption? The [Intel docs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005879/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html) mention different power modes (max performance/medium power saving/max power saving) and I'm wondering how to switch between those.

**Some diagnostic info:**

```
$ lspci | grep -i "wi-fi"                                                                                           130 ↵
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
```

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
# Values are 0 (use default), 1 (ignore/don't touch), 2 (disable) or 3 (enable).
wifi.powersave = 3
```

(Accordingly, `iwconfig` shows "Power Management:on" for the wifi interface.)

[ThinkWiki](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_reduce_power_consumption#intel_wireless) mentions there being a file `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.3/power_level` but the file doesn't exist on my system. The only thing I've found is:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.3/power_state
D0
```

(Not sure what this means)

At the same time, `iwpriv` also doesn't show any driver-specific parameters that I could set:

```
$ iwpriv wlp0s20f3                                                  
wlp0s20f3  no private ioctls.
```

Comment: Which kernel are you running? I guess you are using the built-in kernel module `iwlwifi`, if not, please state which module handles the ax201.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I'm running the default Ubuntu 21.04 kernel (currently 5.11.0-22-generic). According to `$ lspci -v` the kernel driver used by the WiFi card is indeed `iwlwifi`.

Comment: Note that per-component power usage values reported by powertop are completely bogus.

Comment: @intelfx Do you have a source for that? My impression has been that, even if not entirely accurate, the reported values do provide a good indication of which components use a lot of power vs. little power.

Comment: @balu no source except for personally reading the code. There is no way in modern PC hardware to get per-component power usage metrics. What powertop does is purely algorithmic estimation (and the algorithm they use is not exactly sophisticated).

Comment: @balu Case in point: https://i.ibb.co/S63kSmf/2023-04-05-12-33-59.png There is no way the (virtual!) tailscale network interface is responsible for 5W power consumption, just like there is no way the ethernet interface (which is powered down) is responsible for 1.2W of it. At the same time it ridiculously underestimates the Wi-Fi interface and doesn't even try to show the CPU package power usage (which is, ironically, much closer to 5-6W).

Comment: @intelfx "There is no way in modern PC hardware to get per-component power usage metrics. What powertop does is purely algorithmic estimation (and the algorithm they use is not exactly sophisticated)" I see. Thanks for elaborating! As for tailscale in particular, don't forget that tailscale runs Wireguard in userland and that, at least on mobile, tailscale has had a history of battery drain! (Whether or not that userland activity should be associated with the virtual device or the underlying process is a different question of course.)

Comment: @balu yes, I'm aware that tailscale is a userspace wireguard implementation, but there is, again, no way it could be responsible for 5W of power usage. On my laptop, it would have to consume an entirety of a single CPU core to get to those numbers, and it was completely idle at the time of taking that screenshot.

Comment: @balu BTW, the question of battery drain on mobile is completely orthogonal to that matter. Mobiles save power by aggressively powering off unused hardware and deep-sleeping the CPU as much as possible, so mobile battery drain is often a consequence of excessive background activity rather than a consequence of code inefficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and reboot:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/intel_wifi.conf
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi power_save=Y power_level=5
```

Though I'm not sure if it's `power_level=5` or `power_level=1`. The documentation leaves a lot to be desired:

```
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

I've even read the source code and I'm still none the wiser.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this and get back to you! Question on the side: In how far does this `power_level` setting interact with the `powersave` feature that's provided, among others, by the NetworkManager?

Comment: I've no idea to be honest.